# What is the Personal - System Logs item in my inventory?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I see that I have a new category in my inventory named Personal, and it contains an item called System Logs.  What is this for?  Will I need it in the future or can I sell it to make room for other more useful items?

Comment: I just put mine in the bank until I figure out what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The personal category is for an echo that would give you a bit of a backstory regarding whichever character you pick when you first start the game.  I personally haven't found another use besides that.  It was also a feature in Borderlands 2.  I'm unsure whether it was in the original Borderlands.