# What are the Personal Items?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I found that every character has a "Personal Item" in his inventory after you start the game. My question is: What is the purpose of it? I mean yeah you could sell it for 100$ but that really is absolutely nothing. It also doesn't have any stats so what can I use it for?

Comment: Interestingly it can be added to grinder recipes...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Personal - System Logs item in my inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188928/what-is-the-personal-system-logs-item-in-my-inventory)

Comment: This question seems to have the better/more answers and information (even though it's a week newer, see [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha). I'd suggest closing the other question instead of this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out that when clicking it, you will hear dialogue from the character who started with it, so basically it's a small lore-item that sells for a small amount of gold. The dialogue appears to be the same every time you click it, although it differs from class to class.

Answer (score 0):

You can sell it for 100 credits and buy it back for nothing (it will list it as 100 credits, but it will not deduct any).  You could in theory repeat this process for unlimited credits.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you provide a screenshot or something of this?

Comment: Nope, But I promise you it works.

Comment: @RoijanEskor https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/2o15zh/personal_items/

Answer (score -1):

You can sell it for a small amount of starting cash for ammo or medpacks but other than that there is no real use.