# What's the Neuro Backup good for?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

After creating a new character in Borderlands TPS he had an item named "Neuro Backup" in his inventory which looks like an ECHO recorder but doesn't do anything.

Should I just sell it or does it have any value later in the game?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189881 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188928

Answer (score 1):

This echo contains some backstory for your character.  Nothing else.  You can listen to it (I forget if it's the right or left mouse button that activates the recording) or not, sell it, store it in your bank, or just throw it away.